# Question about why an answer was deleted

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, convert-to-comment

SO: 
[Tests are no longer executed through Visual Studio 2010 after Visual Studio 11 beta was installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758204/tests-are-no-longer-executed-through-visual-studio-2010-after-visual-studio-11-b)

Can anyone shed some light on why my answer (that was the correct answer according to the poster) was converted to a comment?

I would have preferred a comment describing the reason rather than a point blank deletion.

Comment: To quote from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) "Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are **barely more than a link to an external site**".  Guess that's probably the reason :)

Comment: It's fixed now, correct? Looks like it was a mistake. sometimes if an answer is slightly on-the-short-side, it can go both ways..

Comment: Well, according to the massive down votes spree here on meta, it doesn't fit into the classification "mistake". I should have known better and crawl back under my rock. Geez.

Comment: @MagnusJohansson - Downvotes should just tickle slightly, it's nothing to get bothered over.

Comment: OK, I stand corrected with a slightly more thickened skin..

Comment: The title of this question in all its passive-aggressive glory is also super annoying.

Comment: @Juhana OK, sorry to have annoyed you. Title fixed.

Comment: While I agree with both of the answers here that your original answer was... lacking..., I would've preferred to see a comment *first* rather than a straight-up conversion to comment.

Comment: @Shog9 No, the conversion to comment was appropriate. This was not an answer. Leaving a comment and coming back later is not a sustainable workflow, especially on SO given how overworked the moderators are. The answerer should have known better than to post a link instead of an answer anyway.

Comment: @Gilles: You weren't involved in this, and aren't aware of the details behind it. As for the bit you *were* involved in: if you want to ease the load on SO mods, don't go flagging an answer after finding a link to it here unless you've already left a comment on it yourself. If more folks used the tools they *do* have access to instead of hiding behind moderators, they'd have considerably more time to actually... moderate.

Comment: @Shog9 I admit that my flag was in error, I realized it 10 seconds later. Unfortunately there's no way to rescind a flag. I stopped commenting when I flag an answer for deletion when I learned that the poster doesn't get notified of comments on deleted posts.

Comment: @Gilles, they don't get notified (*if* the deletion happens before they return to the site), but they can still *see* the comments if they return to their answer wondering why it was removed. More importantly, if they do see and respond with improvement before a moderator gets to the flag, there may well be no action needed at all.

Comment: I'm not a SO moderator, but as its stated in the FAQ, `[why are some posts removed?] barely more than a link to an external site`. I regularly delete link-"answers" on Ask Ubuntu. BoltClock did the right thing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I agree with the conversion. Your original "answer" was nothing more than a link that says "go here to find the answer." That's not what we want. **We want the answer to be here.** We shouldn't actually have to visit the link in order to solve the problem, the link is supposed to be a go-to or source page to read further or confirm your answer. Your second answer does just that.

Answer (score 9):

Your original answer was this:

> Have you checked this: [MSTest not working after installing vs11 next to vs10](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/728659/mstest-not-working-after-installing-vs11-next-to-vs10)

Simply posting links to other websites as an answer are frowned upon here for several reasons, notably that it's lazy not to put the content here, it's annoying to have to visit an external website to see the answer you *expect* here, and most importantly, links go dead. We want the content to remain useful, and a link to nowhere isn't very useful. You should make sure to post at least a minimal summary, as you've just added:

> To paraphrase the official answer from Microsoft in the above link:
>
> > This is a known issue with Visual Studio 2010 which got fixed in 2010
> >     SP1
>
> Get SP1 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23691).

And voilà, your answer is now a real answer - it includes the issue and a solution. BoltClock was right in changing the original to a comment.